# c# Collection modification not taking effect in all WinForms

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Main form of my project is Form 1. This is actually searching Patient window. It has a combobox that is filled with a list of existing patients from the DB. This comboBox is filed with a function written below. This function is called from the constructor.

```
    public void fillComboBox()
    {
        items.Clear();
        items.Add("Select Name");
        MainDataContext context = new MainDataContext(); //dotConnect Linq to sqlite
        var query = from p in context.Patients
                    orderby p.Name ascending
                    select p;
        foreach (Patient p in query)
        {
            items.Add(p.Name);
        }
        comboBox1.DataSource = items;
    }
```

(works fine). items is of type "List<string>". On Creation of every new form i pass the instance of form1. like

> Form3 f3 = new Form3(this);

Ok after a patient is found control goes to Form3 to show Patient info or Edit if required (Works Fine). Then goes to Form4 to build the Growth chart for babies (Works Fine).
The Problem appears when I add a new Patient.
The Control goes from Form1 to Form2 by a Button 'New Patient'.
In Form2 I add a patient then go to Form3 and Form4 (works fine). After i am done with Form4, the control is transfered to Form1 with this code

```
    Form1 f1;
    public Form4(Form1 f1)
    {            
        InitializeComponent(); //and etc
        this.f1 = f1;
    }
    //...other functions etc
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        f1.Show();
    }
```

But the comboBox in Form1 is not Updated. It contains the same old list. But when i created a new Form1 in Form4 like this

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        form1.Show();
    }
```

then it works fine but in this way. there will be one instance of Form1 displayed and the other hidden.
and as description above this new Form1 will CREATE its child Forms (2,3,4). I dont want this so i went back to the previous solution (going to Form1 without creating new instance in Form4). But this leads to No Updation in combobox (in Form1) and When i close my program it gives the Error.

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute;

Tried this code in Form4 too

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        f1.fillcombobox();
        f1.Show();
    }
```

I also tried to override onShown and onLoad events of Form1 but no gain just pain and vain.
Then i tried

> Application.Restart();

in Form2 after a patient is inserted. This surely Helped me out. But leads to another problem. The Control goes to Form1 that i wanted to go to Form3 after a new patient is inserted.

Please Help me out.
I know this is a Mess but your help will be appreciated :)

Comment: using f1.fillcombobox(); should fix the problem for your! what was the result when you used that code?

Comment: old list not having the newly added patient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute;

This error shows that the you are enumerating a collection (a foreach perhaps) and at the same time you are modifying it. This is not allowed. You cannot modify a collection that you are enumerating on.

You need to show the line that is throwing the exception though.

Comment: when i close the application in Form1 > closeform(){this.Close();}

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems you're using the same list instance (called items) and I guess it is a List object, the control does not get notified when content of the list change so the data is not refreshed in UI.

Have you tried using a BindingList for the items collection ? Look at [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: this list is just the names of patients obtained from db and this list is used only in Form1. next i do is just update Database. when go to Form1 there i use fillcombobox();

Comment: Yea, I figured it out. Yet calling fillcombobox doesn't rebind the control to its source. To do so, either try using a BindingLidt or try to call mycombobox.ResetBindings() to force the control to rebind (I don't know if it will work though)

Comment: i changed my whole code so i didnt try this! thanks by the way